# Reactjs - How to pass my json data as options in my select field?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to call API and use it's data as options (specifically the `symbol` JSON field) for my select dropdown.

However It's not working due to: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

I added an example of how my api data looks like below my code.

```
export default function SymbolInput() {

    const [data, setData] = useState({ companies: [] });

    const classes = useStyles();

    useEffect(() => {
        Axios.get("<URL HERE>").then((res) => {
            setData({ companies: res.data });
            console.log(res.data);
        });
    }, [setData]);
    

    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
            <Autocomplete
                multiple
                options={data.companies.symbol}
                getOptionLabel={(option) => option.symbol}
                filterSelectedOptions
                renderInput={(params) => (
                <TextField
                    {...params}
                    variant="outlined"
                    label="filterSelectedOptions"
                    placeholder="Favorites"
                />
                )}
            />
        </div>
    );
}
```

I think the error is coming from not parsing my JSON correctly?
How can I fix my dropdown and make everything work?

API call example data:

```
[{"symbol":"A","company":"Agilent Technologies, Inc."}, 
 {"symbol":"AAL","company":"American Airlines Group, Inc."}, 
 {"symbol":"AAP","company":"Advance Auto Parts, Inc."}, 
 {"symbol":"AAPL","company":"Apple, Inc."}, 
 {"symbol":"ABBV","company":"AbbVie, Inc."}]
```

Comment: data.companies.symbol doesn't make sense, given that your seed data sets data.companies as an empty array.

I suggest you look into what you use for seed data and check if the error is being thrown inside the AutoComplete component while it is rendering with seed data.

Comment: You need to pass an array to `options` property, so did you try to use `data.companies` instead?

Comment: It doesn't seems to have a code to get length. Pls provide the code to solve it.

Comment: @cuongdevjs, that was the actual problem, thank you for helping me. If you want to explain it properly as an answer so I can upvote you, feel free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need pass `data.companies` property instead. Because `options` need to passed by array, `data.companies.symbols` is string.